# How to Select between two periode of month and year eg: january 2018 - january 2019?

Tags: sql-server

SQL query problem

```
select *
from app_contract_hd
where year(created_datetime) between 2018 and 2018 and MONTH(created_datetime)between 4 and 4
```

Comment: What is the data type of the created_datetime column? You can try something like this, if it is stored as string: '2018.01.01' < created_datetime < '2019.01.31'

Comment: the data type is datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `'created_datetime'` column is `'datetime'` data type, you may try the next approach using [DATEFROMPARTS()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function:

```
SELECT *
FROM app_contract_hd
WHERE CONVERT(date, created_datetime) BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(2018, 1, 1) AND DATEFROMPARTS(2019, 1, 1)
```

Additionally, if your want to filter your data with specific hour, use [DATETIMEFROMPARTS()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetimefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT *
FROM app_contract_hd
WHERE created_datetime BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0) AND DATEFROMPARTS(2019, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

if the data type is Datetime

```
select * from app_contract_hd
where year(created_datetime) between cast('2018-01-01 00:00:00' as datetime) and  cast('2019-01-31 23:59:59' 
as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try simple code:

```
select *
from app_contract_hd
where '2018-01-01' <= created_datetime and created_datetime < '2019-02-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have TIME in your created_datetime field, its better if you check the upper range less than +1 day with your original upper range date

```
SELECT *
FROM app_contract_hd
WHERE created_datetime >= '20180101'
AND created_datetime < '20180201'
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
SELECT * FROM APP_CONTRACT_HD

WHERE 
(YEAR(CREATED_DATETIME) >=2018 AND MONTH(CREATED_DATETIME)>=1) 

OR
(YEAR(CREATED_DATETIME) <=2019 AND MONTH(CREATED_DATETIME)<=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way using `CONCAT` and checking with `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT *
FROM app_contract_hd
WHERE CONCAT(YEAR(created_datetime), MONTH (created_datetime)) BETWEEN 201801 AND 201901
```